# C# dll creating and save application settings in another project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I have a create a dll. A WPF project (start up project) references this dll. I want the dll to store certain values in the settings file of the WPF project. If the settings do not exist at run time I want the dll to create them. Is this possible? I seem to be going around in circles.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that the DLL file contains class(es). So you should create instance of each class that you want. then serialize them and you can save them and restore.

Comment: AFAIK This is the standard behavior for DLLs with configuration files: settings are stored and read from the application settings